# Degrees of comparison for words ending in "-ly"

Tags: adverbs, modifiers, degree-of-comparison

Would you make a word ending in *-ly* positive, comparative, or superlative?
I'm sort of leaning towards positive at the moment, and if the answer is positive, would you put *more* and *most* for comparative and superlative, respectively (e.g., *more excitedly*, *most excitedly*, etc.)? Actually, now that I think about it, it doesn't sound like it makes sense...

Comment: I would make it in many cases an **adverb**. This is a _great_ book , I enjoyed it _greatly_.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what part of speech the word ending in *-ly* is; is it an adjective, or an adverb? It also depends on what type of comparison (if any) is being made.

Not all words that end in -ly are adverbs, and not all adverbs end in -ly. So what is an adverb? An [adverb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adverb) modifies verbs, adjectives, other adverbs, or even whole phrases and sentences. In contrast, an adjective merely modifies nouns. As [these Merriam-Webster entries](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ly) indicate, the *-ly* suffix can be used to form either adjectives or adverbs (although it is usually used to form adverbs). For instance, the words *bodily* and *dastardly* are both adjectives, despite the deceptive *-ly* ending. [This post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/are-words-ending-in-ly-adverbs) explains more about the double use of *-ly*, as well as the suffix's origin. Similarly, some adverbs, known as *[flat adverbs](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/do-all-adverbs-end-in-ly)*, do not have the *-ly* suffix. For instance, you would say *jump high*, even though *high* modifies *jump*; *high* can be both an adjective and adverb (no *-ly* necessary).

---

Once you have determined whether the word is an adjective of adverb (if you can't deduce it from the word's usage, you can always use a dictionary to identify the part of speech), you can now form the word with different degrees of comparison. Fortunately, the comparative and superlative forms of adjectives and adverbs are formed using related methods. But what is the difference between the comparative, superlative, and positive? The *comparative* is used for comparing *two things*. The *superlative* is used for comparing *more than two things*. However, if you just want to use a plain adjective or adverb *without comparison*, you use the *positive*. To use the comparative or superlative with adjectives, [follow these simple rules](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/comparative-and-superlative-adjectives). To use the comparative or superlative with adverbs, [follow these similar rules](http://www.eflnet.com/tutorials/advcompsup.php#.U6YjNpRdWSo). Note that some adverbs are formed irregularly. The adjective *good* has a corresponding adverb *well*, which has the comparative form *better* and the superlative form *best*. Here are some examples of a positive, comparative, and superlative adverb, as follows:

> The mouse was walking *quietly*.
>   The mouse was walking *more quietly* than the rat.
>   Of all the rodents, the mouse was walking *most quietly*.

Additionally, the examples given in your question (*more excitedly* and *most excitedly*) are indeed the correct comparative and superlative forms of the adverb *excitedly*. You will find that comparative and superlative adverbs are used *more commonly* than you think.